# Prove that the integral of Weibull distribution from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ $= 1$

Tags: integration, probability-distributions

Given: $f(x) = \beta /\theta^\beta x^{\beta -1}e^{-(x/\theta)^\beta}$

this can be rewritten as

$$\begin{align} f(x) &= \beta(1/\theta)(1/\theta)^{\beta -1 }x^{\beta -1}e^{-(x/\theta)^\beta} \\
&=(\beta/\theta)(x/\theta)^{\beta -1 }e^{-(x/\theta)^\beta}\,dx \\
&= (\beta/\theta)\int (x/\theta)^{\beta -1 }e^{-(x/\theta)^\beta} \, dx 
\end{align}$$

Can someone help from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, substitute $u=\frac{x}{\theta}$ in the integral.

Then just notice that the derivative of $e^{-u^{\beta}}$ is $-\beta u^{\beta -1 }$$e^{-u^{\beta}}$.

Edit : the support of the Weibull distrubution is $[0,+\infty[$, not $]-\infty,+\infty[$